# gatsby static image 0X0

Tags: image, sass, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I'm using the new gatsby image plugin, and `StaticImage`. I have got a few images on the website, all works perfect normally beside one that only has the black background

[image: black bg]

(source of black, change the bg color attribute to `red` for example change the view to red)

The`<picture>` tag has 0X0 pixels

[image: 0X0]

Another weird thing is the auto-created `div` container has a max-width of 47px, though the image is bigger than that (in all rest cases the max-width actually corresponds to the image dimensions)

[image: 47px]

[image: dimesions]

relevant code

```
// js
 <div className="advertising">
   <StaticImage
              className="advertising-img"
              src="../images/advertising.png"
              alt="advertising"
   />
```

```
//scss
  .advertising {
      position: relative;
      margin: 123px 162px 150px 536px;
      .advertising-img {
        width: 260px;
        height: 230px;
        position: absolute;
        left: -460px;
        top: -15px;
      }
```

page lookout (for understanding the CSS a little bit and show another picture that working..)

[image: page]

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

**edit**

live site - https://catsh-landing-page.netlify.app/

Comment: Can you provide a sanbox or a live site?

Comment: added live site to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request to advertising image is blocked by the browser, as you can see by opening the dev tools.

[image]

In addition, the fact that is working on my mobile phone (screenshot below):

[image]

Makes me think that the image is blocked by the browser itself or by some extensions (AdBlock, etc) because of the name to avoid advertisers or publicity by default.
Try changing the name of the image or try disabling the extensions.

Comment: indeed AdBlock extension was the cause. thanks, never would think of it!